# How to remove all downloads and action files in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using SimpleCache to store the Dash chunks I download with ExoPlayer's DownloadService, the chunks are stored in the folder DOWNLOAD_CONTENT_DIRECTORY. My DownloadManager also saves the DownloadActions in the folder DOWNLOAD_ACTION_FILE. I want to clear all my download related files from disk. The simplest solution I can think of is to directly delete all files stored in those directories, but I don't know if that's the right way to do it without compromising anything else in ExoPlayer. The other way I thought was to call DownloadService.startWithAction(removeDownloadAction) for every download I have, but in this case I want to remove all downloads indiscriminately.

```
public Cache getDownloadCache(Context context) {
    if (downloadCache == null) {
        File downloadContentDirectory = new File(getDownloadDirectory(context), DOWNLOAD_CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        downloadCache = new SimpleCache(downloadContentDirectory, new NoOpCacheEvictor());
    }
    return downloadCache;
}

public File getDownloadDirectory(Context context) {
    File downloadDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    if (downloadDirectory == null) {
        downloadDirectory = context.getFilesDir();
    }
    return downloadDirectory;
}
```

This is how I create my DownlodManager

```
private synchronized void initDownloadManager() {
    if (downloadManager == null) {
        DownloaderConstructorHelper downloaderConstructorHelper =
                new DownloaderConstructorHelper(getDownloadCache(this), DataSourceUtil.buildHttpDataSourceFactory(this));
        downloadManager =
                new DownloadManager(
                        downloaderConstructorHelper,
                        MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS,
                        DownloadManager.DEFAULT_MIN_RETRY_COUNT,
                        new File(getDownloadDirectory(this), DOWNLOAD_ACTION_FILE));

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: I've been deleting all files in the directories and that works fine for me.

Comment: If there are multiple downloads and i want to delete only one download?

Comment: Then you should send a delete intent to your ExoPlayer download service with the uri or id of the download.

Comment: Use DownloadManager.removeAllDownloads or DownloadService.sendRemoveAllDownloads.